# accessing public Box folder using API

Tags: .net, box

A government agency I work with posts data files on a publicly shared Box account every morning (link [here](https://hpdnyc.app.box.com/s/zjq4iwixgn44gvqt43ou4jmiqfehemkc)). I'd like to programmatically pull down the files from that day using the Box API. However, I'm having great difficulty figuring this out, as all the documentation I've seen so far regarding the Box API involves accessing files from your own Box account (or one which you have the credentials for). This is not my Box account, so I don't have those credentials, but the data is intended to be freely accessible to the public. How would I go about doing this?

I'm working in .NET, but if the steps are laid out for me in another language I think I'd be able to adapt it from there.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it like this using box-java-sdk:

```
 BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection userApi = BoxDeveloperEditionAPIConnection.getAppUserConnection(managedUser.getID(), CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, encryptionPref, accessTokenCache);

            BoxItem.Info boxItem = BoxFolder.getSharedItem(api, "https://hpdnyc.app.box.com/s/zjq4iwixgn44gvqt43ou4jmiqfehemkc");
            BoxFolder publicFolder = (BoxFolder)boxItem.getResource();
            Iterable<com.box.sdk.BoxItem.Info> items = publicFolder.getChildren();
            for (BoxItem.Info item : items) {
                System.out.println("\t" + item.getName());
            }
```

The output is:

Ken.Domen.Test ACTIVE
    Complaints20170126.zip
    Complaints20170127.zip
    Complaints20170128.zip
    Complaints20170129.zip
    Complaints20170130.zip
    Complaints20170131.zip
    Complaints20170201.zip
    Violations20170126.zip
    Violations20170127.zip
    Violations20170128.zip
    Violations20170129.zip
    Violations20170130.zip
    Violations20170131.zip
    Violations20170201.zip

Comment: Thank you for that. However, despite my initial assumption that I'd be able to do so, I can't seem to adapt that to .Net. There doesn't seem to be comparable methods for these objects in the .Net SDK!

Comment: I opened an issue with Box and we'll see if they get back to us:  https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/issues/279

Comment: Can you clarify for me if you need a developer API token to make this work?

Comment: I was just using jwt service account.  So I verified with Box that the api doesn't exist in the .NET SDK.  This only works in box-java-sdk.